# How to make .apk web installation using PHP

Tags: php, html

I have this HTML code

```
<a href="www.mywebsite/apk/subway.apk">INSTALL NOW</a>
```

I know absolutely the link above will download an APK file and let user install manually.

So what I need, when someone clicks on "INSTALL NOW" link that the APK file to automatically be downloaded and installed in to the Android device. Like Play Store.

Is it possible in PHP? If it is not, what language can I use to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Not Possible with php
Playstore is an app which does the extraction and installation.
with php you get the user to download apk file or redirect to playstore address only.
Or third would be your own app installed on the user device which
using custom scheme like

```
<intent-filter>
        <data android:scheme="http" android:host="mywebsite.com"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
```

This will redirect to your android app which will do the rest downloading and installation